# aws-amplify/ui-react using a SAML identity provider with Authenticator or withAuthenticator

Tags: reactjs, azure-active-directory, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

In AWS Cognito, I have a User pool with Azure as an external identity provider (SAML). From App Client Settings, I have the option "Launch Hosted UI", I click, I use my Azure credentials - redirects (currently) to localhost - perfect.

From what I can tell Authenticator and withAuthenticator can both be passed a `federated={myFederatedConfig}`

The question then is how, when I'm using a SAML provider, and not the four typical given in examples (AWS, Google, Facebook, Apple, etc.)

If anyone could point me, I'd much appreciated.