# AWS cognito - account from external provider gives error "User does not exist"

Tags: reactjs, amazon-cognito

I have a cognito account with users generated by Cognito, and they work just fine.

In a React App I'm using the aws-amplify React UI Libaries.
I.e. import { Authenticator, useAuthenticator, View } from "@aws-amplify/ui-react";

In the Cognito account, I have a user generated via a 3rd party Identity provider (using SAML - Azure AD). The user status is "External_provider". When that user is used to logon, Console error is "User does not exist".

If I use Authenticator i.e. from the React App, to make a new User - it creates just fine, in Cognito and can be used for logon.

Note: This is similar but not the same to my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73285303/aws-amplify-ui-react-using-a-saml-identity-provider-with-authenticator-or-withau)

Comment: The link in your questions is broken. Are users showing up on you cognito console? Do you have multiple apps set up in cognito?

Comment: Thanks Ninad, link fixed. Yes, users are showing up in cognito console. Both from Cognito generation and from the 3rd party IDP. I do have multiple user pools, each with it's own app.

Comment: Wait. Do you have separate user pool for regular registration and external provider?

Comment: Hey Ninad, no - same.

Comment: Ok Can you give more details of how you are using them when you get the user does not exist error? Trying to replicate this.

Comment: The relevent line of code is the one where you try to authenticate. I am guessing that's where the error is being thrown. I want to see which api you are using to make that call. If it is admin or regular. Without that information it is impossible to narrow down what could be going wrong.